# How to impute missing observations in subsequent rows?

Tags: r, spss

I'm having difficulties with some recoding (filling in empty cells in R or SPSS)

I'm working with a long format data-set (in order to run a multilevel model) where each respondent (ID-variable) has three rows, so three times the same ID number below each other (for three different momemts in time).

The problem is that for a second variable (ancestry of respondent) only the first row has a value but the two second rows for each respondent misses that (same) value (0/1). Can any one help? I'm only used to recoding within the same row... below a the data format.

```
ID      Ancestry    
1003    1
1003    .
1003    .
1004    0
1004    .
1004    .
1005    1
1005    .
1005    .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `na.locf` assuming that `.` implies `NA` values.

```
 library(zoo)
 df1$Ancestry <- na.locf(df1$Ancestry)
```

If the column is non-numeric i.e. have `.` as values, then we need to convert it to numeric so that the `.` coerce to NA and then we apply `na.locf` on it

```
 df1$Ancestry <- na.locf(as.numeric(df1$Ancestry))
 df1$Ancestry
 #[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

If it needs to be grouped by "ID"

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, Ancestry := na.locf(Ancestry), by = ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

In SPSS this should do the job, assuming the "Ancestry" variable is numeric:

```
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES OVERWRITEVARS=YES/BREAK=ID /Ancestry=MAX(Ancestry).
```

If "Ancestry" is a string, you could go this way:

```
sort cases by ID Ancestry (d).
if ID=lag(ID) and Ancestry="" Ancestry=lag(Ancestry).
execute.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way of achieving this is in `R` the following, using the fact that the actual value always occurs in the first position for each ID:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Ancestry = Ancestry[1])

Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
Groups: ID [3]

     ID Ancestry
  (int)    (chr)
1  1003        1
2  1003        1
3  1003        1
4  1004        0
5  1004        0
6  1004        0
7  1005        1
8  1005        1
9  1005        1
```

If you prefer a `base` solution, I think what I would probably have done is the following, though there are many ways of achieving the same: First, note that if `df` is your dataframe, then

```
 df$Ancestry <- as.numeric(df$Ancestry)
```

will coerce the `.` into `NA`. Then we could use

```
df_id <- df[complete.cases(df),]
df$Ancestry <- NULL
df <- merge(df, df_id, all.x = T)
```

which gives the same output. Here, I take a `dataframe` that consists only of complete entries, and `merge` it back onto the original `dataframe`.

Answer (score 2):

Once you convert the `.`s to `NA` by your favorite method, this is exactly what `tidyr::fill` was designed to do:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% extract(Ancestry, 'Ancestry', convert = TRUE) %>% fill(Ancestry)
# 
#     ID Ancestry
# 1 1003        1
# 2 1003        1
# 3 1003        1
# 4 1004        0
# 5 1004        0
# 6 1004        0
# 7 1005        1
# 8 1005        1
# 9 1005        1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF (ID EQ LAG(ID)) Ancestry=LAG(Ancestry).
```

Or alternatively:

```
IF (ID EQ LAG(ID) AND MISSING(Ancestry)) Ancestry=LAG(Ancestry).
```